# Laravel URL Architecture

Tags: php, url, laravel, laravel-routing

I am building a social networking application using Laravel 5, and I am slightly confused about the structure of the URLs.

Using a previous Stack Overflow post from another member, I have managed to grasp the basics (profiling, account, etc). Here is what I have so far:

```
http://myapp.com/account/create

http://myapp.com/account/login
http://myapp.com/account/logout

http://myapp.com/account/verify
http://myapp.com/account/verify/{token}
http://myapp.com/account/settings

http://myapp.com/profile/FooMan
```

And that's all well and good (at least I think so - any tips are welcome), but how do I go about creating a URL structure for things such as friends? I get that you could have:

```
http://myapp.com/profile/FooMan/friends
```

But to me, that seems ugly. And if I wanted to add a "/add" route to the friends, how would I go about that also? Thank you in advance!

P.S. On some of the pages, such as "login" and "create" I use the route::get() to display the form, and route::post() to submit the details to the controller. Is this bad practice?

Comment: Why does it look ugly? I think it looks good? Or is FooMan the current user and you want `profile/my-friends` ?

Comment: I think it's a bit of both. For example, when a user wants to add a friend, which url would that be? `profile/FooMan2/add`?

Comment: Hmm I am not really seeing the issue? You could drop profile all together, and just have `domain.com/fooman2` for someone elses profile, and `domain.com/friends` for current users connections. This is pretty standard just navigate around twitter and facebook.

Comment: I thought about that, but then what about when we're creating new pages and it overlaps with somebody's username?

Comment: You need a list of reserved words before going live - you wouldn't be allowed to create a username `friends, create, unfollow` etc much like reserved words in a programming language. I am sure twitter doesn't allow you to signup with the account name `followers`. You will only have at most 10 or 20 root route actions so its not hard to add to your validation

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for your help. Do you want to post that last comment as an answer so I can mark you as the answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following a standard system such as facebook or twitter would help with your routing approach.

To avoid lengthy urls, you can route directly to a profile via their user name, using a route such as:

```
Route::get('{username}', ...);
Route::get('{username}/friends', ...);
// etc

// Current user
Route::get('friends', ...);
```

Now, there will be occasions where a username may conflict with a core action such as `domain.com/friends` or `domain.com/login`. Establish a list of core actions and restrict users from signing up with those keywords. This is simple by using laravel's `not in` validation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this has been most useful. I shall use this approach!

Comment: Cool no problem. Goodluck